# Angularjs: Updating a directive scope variable from controller not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm new to [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) and have a bit of trouble trying to do this simple task of updating a scope variable I set in my directive in the calling controller.

So I have a directive:

```
app.directive('pageShell', function (){
    return{
        restrict: 'AE',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true
        scope:{
            title: '@',
            body: '@',
            footer: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="title-content">{{title}}</div>' +
                  '<div class="body-content">{{body}}</div>' +
                  '<div class="footer-content">{{footer}}</div>'
    }
});
```

so in my html:

```
<page-shell title="Header" body="this is my body" footer="Footer" />
```

in my controller:

app.c

```
ontroller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {

    // TEST 1 - simple scope change
    // switch pages or content so change some values
    if(pageIndex === 2) {
      $scope.title = "Page 2 title";
      $scope.body = "Page 2 body content";
      $scope.footer = "Page 2 footer";
    }

    // TEST 2 - change by using apply
    $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.title = "Page 2 title";
            $scope.body = "Page 2 body content";
            $scope.footer = "Page 2 footer";
    });
});
```

So I tried in my controller thinking I should have access to my variable in my scope to change it directly but it did not work but did not throw any errors.  Tried using `$apply` but got the error `$apply` is already in progress?  Tried changing to 2-way binding in the scope by using `=` instead of `@` for the title, body, and footer but get a `$parse:syntax` error.

Any clue why this simple task wouldn't work?  Thanks!

Comment: If you get an "Apply already in progress" this means that you are running the apply in a place where angular is already applying a change. Possibly this means something else is going on here! Could you post a Fiddle with your code demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Please fix your code formatting so that it is easy to read. Also please provide the declaration of directive in html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:
My pageShell directive's scope needs to be:

```
scope:{
    title: '=',
    body: '=',
    footer: '='
},
```

The binding needs to be both ways.

the html:

```
<page-shell title="Header" body="this is my body" footer="Footer" />
```

and the controller:

```
Controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {

    // TEST 1 - simple scope change
    // switch pages or content so change some values
    if(pageIndex === 2) {
      $scope.title = "Page 2 title";
      $scope.body = "Page 2 body content";
      $scope.footer = "Page 2 footer";
   }

   // TEST 2 - change by using apply
   $scope.$apply(function() {
   $scope.title = "Page 2 title";
   $scope.body = "Page 2 body content";
   $scope.footer = "Page 2 footer";
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML should be something like this

`<page-shell title="{{title}}" body="{{body}}" footer="{{footer}}" />`